# Smalltalk, how to insert tab in a string

Tags: string, smalltalk

How do you insert a "tab" in a string? I thought it was t enclosed in <> , but I do:

```
'Name <t> Age <t> Occupation'
```

prints exactly how it's typed. I would like to get

```
Name    Age     Occupation
```

instead of

```
Name <t> Age <t> Occupation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'Name ', String tab, ' Age ', String tab, ' Occupation'
```

If String does not understand #tab, you have to :

```
'Name ', Character tab asString, ' Age ', Character tab asString, ' Occupation'
```

Answer (score 2):

As Damien noted, you can simply concatenate several calls to `String tab` to achieve what you wanted.  The `<t>` trick you're trying, though, happens in Squeak-based Smalltalks if you call `expandMacros` on your string.  E.g.,

```
'Here is<t>a tab and<n>a blank line' expandMacros
```

This mechanism is generic, and quite easily extensible; see `String>>expandMacrosWithArguments:` for more information.

Comment: None of those two are working. I'm not using Squeak, I'm using Visual Works. Would that make it a problem?

Comment: Yes; they're Squeak-specific.  I'll find out the VisualWorks variant for you.